# How can I add transitions and transform when creating output with Javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am appending output to a `ul` element using `li` elements. I am able to generate the output as desired but I have no idea on how to use transitions and transform, as Javascript is creating those `li` elements.

I want to transform `li` elements as they appear from Javascript in the DOM.

Vanilla Javascript is preferred.

What I have, HTML:

```
<div class="add">    
<input type="text" id="addTodoTextInput" placeholder="Add Task Here" onkeydown="handlers.addTodo()" >  <!-- input text field to add <li> -->
<button onclick="search()"> <img src="add.png" height="20" width="20" alt=""> </button> <!-- button to add li -->    
</div>
<ul class="result">
    <!-- output generated with JavaScript will be appended here -->
</ul>
```

CSS:

```
li{
    margin: 0 5px 0 5px;
    padding: 5px;
    font-family: cursive;
    color: #006cff;
    font-size: 1.3em;
    background: rgba(43, 229, 43, 0.28);
    transition: 2s;
}

li:hover{
    transform: translateX(50px);
}
```

JavaScript:

```
var handlers = {
    addTodo: function(){
        var addToDoInput = document.getElementById('addTodoTextInput');
        todoList.addToDo(addToDoInput.value);
        addToDoInput.value = "";
        view.displayTodo();
    }
}

var view = {    
    displayTodo: function() {
        var todosUl = document.querySelector('ul');
        todosUl.innerHTML = '';
        todoList.itemList.forEach(function(todo,position) {
            var todosLi = document.createElement('li');
            var todoTextWithCompletion = "";
            if(todo.completed === true) {
                todosLi.style.textDecoration = "line-through";
            }
            todosLi.id = position;
            todosLi.textContent = todo.todoText;
            todosLi.appendChild(this.createDeleteButton());
            todosLi.appendChild(this.createToggleButton());
            todosUl.appendChild(todosLi);
        }, this);
    }
}
```

Comment: *`I want to transform li tags`* or you want *us to transform your LI tags*

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan i am not asking for direct answers man...just tell me something to work on..i'll make my way from there..

Comment: `I am appending my output to ul tag using li tag` so why not just show that code here? So people willing to help can move on from there ... did you read [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)?

Comment: thanks @caramba for that...i didnt read it before, u taught me something valuable . I've edited my post can you tell me if something's still missing... :-)

Comment: Here we go. Next time post your code first. Much simpler to give proper answer tailored for your situation.

Comment: i'm sorry man ..new here..thanks though :)

Answer (score 1):

```js
function insertLI(EL_target, content) {

  var EL_li = document.createElement("li");
  var NODE_content = document.createTextNode(content);

  EL_li.appendChild(NODE_content);
  EL_target.appendChild(EL_li);

  // Register a live classList change in order to trigger CSS transition
  setTimeout(function() {
      EL_li.classList.add("added");
  }, 0);
  
}



var EL_ul = document.getElementById("myUL");
var i = 0;

document.getElementById("add").addEventListener("click", function() {
  insertLI(EL_ul, "I'm number"+ i++);
})
```

```css
ul li{
  opacity: 0;          /* initially set opacity to 0 */
}

.added{
  transition: opacity 1s, color 3s;      /* transition!! yey */
  opacity:1;
  color: fuchsia;
}
```

```html
<button id=add>ADD &lt;li&gt;</button>
<ul id=myUL></ul>
```

Comment: What is the significance of using a `setTimeout` call with `0` for delay to add a class, as opposed to just adding the class then and there? I never did the former, and my applications seem to work just fine without the `setTimout` wrapping things.

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend simple solution with CSS animations. You will need a little change to your code to insert next item after animation of the previous completed. For this replace your for loop with this code:

```
(function insertNext (position) {

  var todosLi = document.createElement('li');
  var todo = todoList.itemList[position];

  var todoTextWithCompletion = "";
  if (todo.completed === true) {
    todosLi.style.textDecoration = "line-through";
  }

  todosLi.id = position;
  todosLi.textContent = todo.todoText;

  todosLi.appendChild(this.createDeleteButton());
  todosLi.appendChild(this.createToggleButton());

  todosLi.addEventListener('animationend', function() {
    if (todoList.itemList.length > position + 1) {
      insertNext(position + 1)
    }
  })

  todosUl.appendChild(todosLi);
}.bind(this))(0)
```

Then all you need to do is add CSS animation into your styles:

```
li {
  /* ... */
  animation: appear 1s forwards;
}

@keyframes appear {
  from {
    opacity: 0; background: #eee;
  }
  to {
    opacity: 1; background: coral;
  }
}
```

**Demo:** https://jsfiddle.net/Lf6t8sre/